# How to use Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) with glew and SharpGL using managed to unmanaged call

Tags: c#, c++-cli, unmanaged, vbo, glew

**EDIT2: I found the solution! I needed to add `RenderContextType="FBO"` inside the OpenGLControl in the .xaml file of my windows form.**

I'm working on a game base on a MVC pattern. The View is in C# and the Model is a C++ library. I choosed C++/CLI as a controller between them. For now, this work fine. My C++ library is a game engine I made that use OpenGL for the render. So I used SharpGL in a WPF application on the C# side. Then, I linked the OpenGL event to the model via the controller. This also works fines. I can call basic OpenGL functions on the C++ side like glVertex, glGenList, and so.

Now, here's the problem. I found that the OpenGL list were to slow for my needs. So I wanted to use VBO. I already use that on another project that was just using C++. So I include glew in my project without forgeting to call glewInit() and checking for errors.

The problem is when I called glGenBuffer it shoot an Access Violation Exceptions. I investigate this problem and found that glew tell me that I do not support OpenGL 2.0... But this is false because I know my computer support it, I have another project in C++ that use these functions and glew tell me that OpenGL 2.0 is supported.

Then I tried to load the extension via wglGetProcAddress. But it return a null pointer.

So I though that even if glewInit() do not throw any error, maybe I do not have the context. So I tried to get the deviceHandle and the renderHandle from the SharpGL.RenderContextProvider and send them to my C++ model then call wglMakeCurrent to take the context. The function do not return any error but it change nothing to my problem.

So yeah, now I really don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT: It is important to add that I already call glewInit() after the context is create and before calling the extensions functions.